# How to use non-static enum values with the DefaultValue data annotation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

```
public enum ProductQuantityType {
    Weight = 1,
    Volume = 2,
    Custom = 0
}
```

This fails

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetaData))]
public partial class Product {
    public class ProductMetaData {
        [DefaultValue(ProductQuantityType.Weight)]
        public object QuantityType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-static enum"? What is ProductQuantityType and what does the Weight member look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, this is probably because your QuantityType field is an `object` (reference type), but your enum is a value type. You should obviously be making that auto-impl-prop either an `int`, or a `ProductQuantityType`.

```
    [DefaultValue(ProductQuantityType.Weight)]
    public ProductQuantityType QuantityType { get; set; }
```

You are aware that DefaultValue is not going to set this field when you instantiate a new ProductMetadata right? If you want it to always have an initial value, you should be setting it in the constructor.